# The sum of subspaces be the smallest containing subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't understand the proof that if $U_1,...,U_m$ are subspaces of a vector space $V$, then $U_1+\ldots+U_m$ is the smallest subspace containing $U_1,...,U_m$. Why does showing that every subspace that contains $U_1,...,U_m$ also contains $U_1+\ldots+U_m$, and that the set $U_1+ \ldots+U_m$ contains each subspace $U_1,...,U_m$ Prove that the subspace $U_1+\ldots+U_m$ is the smallest containing subspace?

Comment: Let W be the smallest subspace containing $U_1,...,U_m$, then it must contain $U_1+\ldots+U_m$ as it is a subspace. So, it is atleast as large as $U_1+\ldots+U_m$.

Answer (score 0):

Because $W:=U_1+\dots +U_n$ is itself a subspace, thus, from the proof, any subspace that contains all $U_i$, also contains $W$, in other words, it is bigger than (or equal to) $W$.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the statement as:

> If $U_1,\dots,U_n$ are subspaces of a vector space $V$, then $U_1+\cdots+U_n$ is the *smallest* subspace of $V$ such that $U_i \subseteq U_1+\cdots+U_n$ for all $i$, that is, if there is some other subspace $W$, of $V$, such that $U_i \subseteq W$ for all $i$, then $U_1+\cdots+U_n \subseteq W$.

Answer (score 0):

As Axler rightly puts, imagine a set $ A = \{1,2,3,4\} $, and take two subset $B = \{1\}$ & $C = \{2\}$. The Largest subset containing B and C is A itself. But the smallest is the union of B and C.

But yes, if $B = \{2,3\}$ then also the union is still the smallest subset containing bot the set.

Now we project this idea in subspaces, if $U$ & $W$ is the subspace, then the smallest subspace containing either one of them is the sum. But, as in sets the sum can be as large as the original vector space, but not smaller than the sum itself.